# Yii CGridView horizontal scroll

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I develop yii application and have CGridView with many columns. I want to scroll the CGridView horizontal but can't find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put grid into container with fixed `width` and `overflow: auto;`.

```
<div class="CGridViewContainer">
    <!-- CGridView here -->
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.CGridViewContainer { width: 960px; overflow: auto; }
```

But I believe that spanning of the columns will be better way of presenting the table. Don't know how to make headers or is it possible w/o modifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `overflow: scroll-x` on the CSS for your grid, that should setup horizontal scrolling in your browser